# How to recognize whether a function is a sync or async?

Tags: python, function, asynchronous, python-decorators

```
from functools import wraps

def timeit(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def timeit_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        if func_is_async:
            result = asyncio.run(func(*args, **kwargs))
        else:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        total_time = end_time - start_time
        logger.info(
            f"Function {func.__name__}: with {args=} {kwargs=} Took {total_time:.4f} seconds"
        )
        return result

    return timeit_wrapper
```

Given the above decorator to time a function, I wondered how to find out whether `func` is sync or async.
In other words, where do I get a bool for `func_is_async`

Comment: [inspect.iscoroutinefunction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.iscoroutinefunction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"where do I get a bool for func_is_async" in the `inspect` module.

If it is a function decorator, and you can use `inspect.iscoroutinefunction(func)`.

However there are nuances - you could have a normal `sync` function or callable that would return an awaitable object, for example  -but as a rule of thumb, `iscoroutinefunction` can work for a decorator to decide wrapping a function in a sync or async way.

Just this week, I wrote some code that did that:

```
from inspect import iscoroutinefunction
from functools import wraps

def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         # decorator work here
         # ...
         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    if iscoroutinefunction(func):
         @wraps(func)
         async def awrapper(*args, **kwargs):
             return wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
         return awrapper
    return wrapper
```